# Can $\mathsf{P}^{\#\mathsf{P}}$ be described in terms of a non-deterministic (alternating) Turing machine?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, turing-machines

Can the $\mathsf{P}^{\#\mathsf{P}}$ (= $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{PP}}$) class be described in terms of a non-deterministic Turing machine (in particular, an alternating Turing machine)? And would a $\mathsf{P}^{\#\mathsf{P}}$ machine be equivalent in computational power to any non-deterministic Turing machine? I suppose it should be because $\mathsf{P}^{\#\mathsf{P}}$ lies in between $\mathsf{PSPACE}$ and $\mathsf{PH}$ as per [this](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/File:Really-important-inclusions.png), and both $\mathsf{PSPACE}$ and $\mathsf{PH}$ are describable in terms of alternating Turing machines. However, I could not find any description of $\mathsf{P}^{\#\mathsf{P}}$ or $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{PP}}$ in terms of alternating Turing machines, so far.

Comment: It is  an open problem weather under SETH, there's a tight reduction from QBF-SAT TO #CNF-SAT as per this talk (~2 minutes before the ending): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIsfsGGOmKI

Comment: @S.D. You could define "Threshold" Turing Machines using counting quantifiers instead of alternating quantifiers and they capture the Counting Hierarchy and in particular $P^{\# P}$. See for example, https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Eric_Allender/publication/2748367_Counting_Hierarchies_Polynomial_Time_And_Constant_Depth_Circuits/links/09e41513dfb20a76e4000000.pdf